# CNContact Frame work not fetching all contacts(iCloud,Gmail)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, contacts

Settings>Contacts>Default Account selected as iCloud and saved a new contact.Then changed Default Account as gmail. CNContactStore not fetching the new saved contact.

```
 CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (granted == YES)
    {
        NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey,CNContactEmailAddressesKey];
        NSArray * contactContainerArray =  [store containersMatchingPredicate:nil error:nil];
        for(CNContainer * container in contactContainerArray) {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:container.identifier];
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply wish to get all unified contacts (Contacts in different accounts that represent the same person may be automatically linked together. Linked contacts are displayed in macOS and iOS apps as unified contacts) the best solution would be below one

```
 -(void)fetchContacts
  {
      CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];    
      [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
      if (granted == YES)
      {
        //keys with fetching properties
        NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey,CNContactEmailAddressesKey];
        NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
        NSArray * contactContainerArray =  [store containersMatchingPredicate:nil error:nil];
        CNContactFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc]initWithKeysToFetch:keys];
        [store enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil usingBlock:^(CNContact * _Nonnull contact, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        }];
      }
  }
```

Comment: Great Solution Vaisakh. Also Could you please let me know how to identify the contact belongs to which "Account" ? Means how to identify that a particular contact is from iCloud or Gmail or Local Address book ?

Comment: I have already asked my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133669/how-to-get-account-name-from-contact-framework

Comment: @MitBhatt Actual question will give you All contacts by containers ( A user may have contacts in their device’s local account or server accounts configured to sync contacts. Each account has at least one container of contacts. A contact can be in only one container.)

Comment: Got it, but how to get name of that container ?

Comment: @MitBhatt check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133669/how-to-get-account-name-from-contact-framework this link

Comment: @MitBhatt Worked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145126/discussion-between-vaisakh-and-mit-bhatt).